# MVC Controller w/ two arguments of same ViewModel type does not bind correctly

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following controller action:

```
public JsonResult AcceptChanges(RoomPricing currentData, RoomPricing lastSaveData)
{
...
}
```

This controller receives JSON encoded objects from my AJAX request:

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    url: _controllerURL,
    data: JSON.stringify({ currentData: _currentData, lastSaveData: _lastSaveData }),
    ...
});
```

The AJAX request data is derived from a form in my partial view, which uses a ViewModel of type `RoomPricing`.  Current and lastSave data are respectively the updated and stale serialized versions of the form.  The purpose of these objects is to do form update checks server-side.  Server-side because the `RoomPricing` model includes an enumerable and other junk that would make reliable update checking complex and obnoxious to perform client-side.

Now, when the controller receives the currentData and lastSaveData, it automagically creates the RoomPricing objects, BUT both objects are identical, taking on the values of currentData.  To be clear: lastSaveData is created, but only in name, as its contents are identical to that of currentData (and so ignoring the data that was passed by AJAX, which I assume goes into the void).

I expect that this behavior is a side effect of MVC trying to be helpful with Model Binding.  Does anyone have a suggestion for getting around this problem?  Making a super-ViewModel with two RoomPricing objects to use as the controller argument did not resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance!

*Edit: The current and lastSave data comes from the following JQuery code:*

```
var $lastSaveFormData = null;
    function AjaxSubmitForm() {
        var $lastSaveSerialized = ($lastSaveFormData == null ? null : $lastSaveFormData)

        var $form = $('#MyForm');

        submitOverrideForm(
            $form.serialize(),      // currentData
            $lastSaveSerialized,    // lastSaveData
            $form.attr('action'),
            );

        $lastSaveFormData = $form.serialize();
    }
```

Through the above I'm able to keep a record of all changes since the last save.  Although the models are somewhat complex, the size of the data being sent is quite small so I figured I'd compare the data server-side, and here we are.  Last thing of note is that I've verified that at this point - `JSON.stringify({ currentData: _currentData, lastSaveData: _lastSaveData }` - the encoded data is as expected...currentData and lastSaveData are unique if form updates have taken place.

*Edit: I just noticed something else.  Here is the data being sent to the server as well as the data received server-side just prior to being bound to the model:*

_currentData, @ AJAX call:

> "Book%5B0%5D.Author=1&Book%5B0%5D.Title=100&Book%5B0%5D.IsPaperback=false&Book%5B1%5D.Author=2&Book%5B1%5D.Title=**2222**&Book%5B1%5D.IsPaperback=false"

_lastSaveData @ AJAX call:

> "Book%5B0%5D.Author=1&Book%5B0%5D.Title=100&Book%5B0%5D.IsPaperback=false&Book%5B1%5D.Author=2&Book%5B1%5D.Title=**77**&Book%5B1%5D.IsPaperback=false"

JSON received server-side, just before model binding:

> {"currentData": "Book[0].Author: 1,1 Book[0].Title: 100,100
>   Book[0].IsPaperback: false,false Book[1].Author: 2,2 Book[1].Title:
>   **2222,77** Book[1].IsPaperback: false,false", "lastSaveData":"false"}

Its like MVC is trying to bind the distinct values to a single model, realizes it cant, and drops the 'lastSave' data.  Then, when the model hits the controller, it discovers that two models are anticipated, so it uses this model for both.  Why is it behaving like this and how can I fix it?

Comment: What happens if you remove the call to `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: Removing ^ causes both objects to be null, i.e. instead of the binding simply being incorrect, instead fails altogether.

Comment: I meant to say `data: { currentData: _currentData, lastSaveData: _lastSaveData }`

Comment: Right, sorry I wasn't clear - I understood what you meant.  Doing what you suggest (making the code appear as you've written above) results in both objects being set to null in the controller.

Comment: Ok. How are you building the data?

Comment: I edited my post above to answer you.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think the problem is that you are sending a single object "data:{.., ..}" <-- one object. Try creating a view model that contains both (current and save data) and accept the view model as the parameter instead. And you don't need stringify.

Comment: @Twenty40 From what I found about sending multiple parameters to the controller, it didn't seem like I should need to stringify either.  BUT, if I don't use it, I get no data at all. This could be the crux of the whole thing...why could it be that when I don't use stringify, I get null data?

Comment: So i just try your approach and it work fine for me. (without stringify). stringify with convert the JSON object to a string. make sure the objects are populated before sending them to the action. Maybe console log the "_currentData" and "_lastSaveData " before the $.ajax to see if they are not null.

Comment: Interesting! Hmm...I'll take another look and get back to you.  I can say for certain that the objects are fully populated before the ajax call; it must be something else I'm not seeing.

Comment: Unclear what your trying to do here. Best guess is your trying to include a copy of the saved object in the view which is only going to degrade performance and open yourself to overposting attacks. Post your current object and get the last saved object from the database in the POST method if your wanting to do some comparisons. But if you want to persist with this approach, use a view model containing 2 properties - one for each `RoomPricing` object and post that view model.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another ViewModel:

```
public class CurrentAndLastSavedRoomPricingViewModel
{
   RoomPricing CurrentData {get;set;} 
   RoomPricing LastSaveData {get;set;} 
}
```

and get it in controller:

```
public JsonResult AcceptChanges(CurrentAndLastSavedRoomPricingViewModel data)
{
...
}
```

passing this model with ajax:

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    url: _controllerURL,
    data: {data: { currentData: _currentData, lastSaveData: _lastSaveData }},
    ...
});
```

**Or you can get last saved data on server from database and don't pass it from client.**

Comment: Hey Kirill, thanks for the response.  I've implemented your recommendation verbatim but to no avail.  The controller is unable to bind the request data to the RoomPricing models, so both currentData and lastSaveData are null :(

Comment: Using this view model approach it needs to be `data: $('form').serialize()`